# Angular 5 want to get value from ngx-bootstrap modal to a component

Tags: angular, angular5

I want to get a value from ngx-bootstrap modal to a parent component (from where the modal is called/ opened). The scenario is, clicking on a hyperlink in the parent component will open a modal. When I clicked on the submit button in the modal, the data will pass to the parent component.

In the parent component `.ts` file, I wrote the following:

```
this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(DeliveryaddressotpModalComponent, {});
```

In the modal `.html` file,

```
<button name="btnGo" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" type="button" (click)="submitForm()">Go</button>
```

In the modal `.ts` file:

```
submitForm(){
  console.log("submit button in modal clicked");
  this.clicked = true;
}
```

**My questions is**: How can I get the value of `this.clicked` in the parent component?

Here is the entire parent component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal-ref.service';
import { RegistrationService } from '../../services/registration.service';
import { AddressbookModalComponent } from '../../shared/components/addressbook-modal/addressbook-modal.component';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-addressbook',
    templateUrl: './addressbook.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./addressbook.component.scss']
})

export class AddressbookComponent implements OnInit {

isMediumScreen: boolean;
    sidebar: boolean;
    isCollapsed: boolean;
    bsModalRef: BsModalRef;
    userShippingAddress : Array<object>;
    userAddress = new UserAddress();
    addressId : any = '';
    phcode : any;
    altphcode : any;
    constructor(
        private ngZone: NgZone,
        private modalService: BsModalService,
        private auth: RegistrationService,
        private content: ContentService,
        public toastr : ToastrService,
        public spinner : NgxSpinnerService,
        public router: Router,
    ) { }

modifyAddress(addressId,type){
if(data.results[0].isDefaultShipping == 1){
    this.auth.sendOtpForModifyShippingAddress(data.results[0].userId).subscribe((data:any) =>{
        this.spinner.hide();
        this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(DeliveryaddressotpModalComponent, {});
        this.bsModalRef.content.closeBtnName = 'Close';
    });
}
}
```

Below is the modal code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { NgForm }   from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { RegistrationService } from '../../../services/registration.service';
import { ContentService } from '../../../services/content.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-deliveryaddressotp-modal',
 templateUrl: './deliveryaddressotp-modal.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./deliveryaddressotp-modal.component.scss']
})
export class DeliveryaddressotpModalComponent implements OnInit {

 userId : number;
 otp:any;

 constructor(
  public regService : RegistrationService,
  public bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
  public toastr : ToastrService,
  private content: ContentService,
  ) {
   this.userId = this.regService.item.user.id;
  }

 ngOnInit() {

 }

 onSubmit(){
 }

 submitForm(){
  console.log("submit opt");

 }

}
```

Comment: post the parent component

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka -posted the parent component.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `public modalCLicked : BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false)` in a shared service and inject it in both your modal service and parent component.  Then in the submitForm call it. Like this:

```
submitForm(){
  console.log("submit button in modal clicked");
  this.clicked = true;
this.modalCLicked.next(this.clicked);
}
```

In your parent component access it like this:

```
this.modalCLicked .asObservable().subscribe(val => console.log("modal clicke", val);):
// do whatever you what it in subscribe()
```

Comment: I already have some shared services. I called the same like `import { RegistrationService } from '../../../services/registration.service';` Now tell me how can I create `public modalClicked : BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false)` ?

Comment: created the variable in the registration.service.ts

Comment: When I added the line: `this.modalCLicked.next(this.clicked);` in the modal ts file, it shows me the error > error TS2339: Property 'modalCLicked' does not exist on type 'DeliveryaddressotpModalComponent'.

Comment: no actually you have to call it with registration service instance. use this.[registrationServiceInstanceName].modalCLicked.next()

Comment: In parent component, in where I have to write the following `this.modalCLicked .asObservable() ... ` ?

Comment: Can you see the parent component code as posted in my question?

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara ngx-boostrap already has api to get data on close. It's simple. Check my answer

Comment: Inside your ngOnit() of the parent component

Comment: I see an error: `Property 'asObservable' does not exist on type ...`

Comment: It should be asObservable() . Also can you post the code you are trying on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe onHide method  provided by ngx-bootstrap-modal :

```js
// in your compoenent.ts 
//import these  
import { ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

// constructor 

 constructor(
              ..........
        private modalService: BsModalService,
        private changeDetection: ChangeDetectorRef,
          ........
        
    ) {
    }

 modifyAddress(addressId,type){
if(data.results[0].isDefaultShipping == 1){
    this.auth.sendOtpForModifyShippingAddress(data.results[0].userId).subscribe((data:any) =>{
        this.spinner.hide();
        this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(DeliveryaddressotpModalComponent, {});
        this.bsModalRef.content.closeBtnName = 'Close';
        this.subscribeData();
        }
        }
 
 // subscribe onhide 
 subscribeData(){
   Observable.combineLatest(
            this.modalService.onHide
        ).subscribe(() => this.changeDetection.markForCheck());
        
         this.modalService.onHide.subscribe(() => {
           let value =  this.bsModalRef.content.clicked; // will contain cliked value 
             console.log('cliked status ',value);
        });
    }

 }
 
 /// in your modal 
 
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import { NgForm }   from '@angular/forms';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { RegistrationService } from '../../../services/registration.service';
import { ContentService } from '../../../services/content.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-deliveryaddressotp-modal',
 templateUrl: './deliveryaddressotp-modal.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./deliveryaddressotp-modal.component.scss']
})
export class DeliveryaddressotpModalComponent implements OnInit {

 userId : number;
 otp:any;
  clicked;
 constructor(
  public regService : RegistrationService,
  public bsModalRef: BsModalRef,
  public toastr : ToastrService,
  private content: ContentService,
  ) {
   this.userId = this.regService.item.user.id;
  }

 ngOnInit() {

 }

 onSubmit(){
 }

// here
 submitForm(){
  console.log("submit button in modal clicked");
    this.clicked = true;
    this.bsModalRef.hide();  // willl hide the modal
 }
```

```html
 <!-- in modal.html  -->

<button name="btnGo" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" type="button" (click)="submitForm()">Go</button>
```

Note that the hide method gets called several times. You need to add additional condition if you want to get the value only one inside onHide Callback.

link :        https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#directive-events

Comment: This is only for the hide / open case. Can I get the value in parent when I submit the btn from modal ?

Comment: dont you want to close modal on submit click ?

Comment: Yes obviously. I've implemented your code but it return undefined in console log and only when I close the modal. Not on submit btn clicked.

Comment: can you produce stalkblitz ... i will modify

Comment: Sorry No Idea about - stalkblitz. Apology.

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara  https://stackblitz.com/ -- you can create minimum reproducable code

Comment: Because your code is written as: `this.modalService.onHide`. So it take the value when I closed the modal. can I modify it so that when click the btn on modal, I can catch the value in parent component?

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara no.. these are events supported by ngx-bootstrap-modal ...

Comment: Will try stalkblitz on 31st. will inform you then.

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara  try printing :  `this.bsModalRef.content` and see what it prints. also can you post your complete modal code. i have worked on such kind of requirement. i can surely help

Comment: I have added the modal code in my question. Please check and suggest.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185882/discussion-between-programoholic-and-niladri-banerjee-uttarpara).

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara  how are closing the modal ?

Comment: I'm not closing this modal. But it would be good if you can write code for closing the modal and in parent component, catch the value of the variable `let a = true` within the `submitForm()`

Comment: @NiladriBanerjee-Uttarpara did you try ?